# Removing items from show view

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am developing an application using Eclipse Photon. In the Window --> show view option, so many items are being displayed. I need to control what gets displayed and what does not.

I did not find any ways to do the same. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to do this with the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point - but it will require a lot of research to work out the view ids. Or just don't include the plugins that contribute the views in your RCP build.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to

> control what gets displayed and what does not

I would recommend to implement your own "Show View" action and remove the standard one. It will be much cheaper to do. However, having

> so many items displayed

may mean that you need to inspect your dependencies more carefully.

Also please note, that during debug launch you **may** see the contributions from the target bundles and this is not equal with what you will get in the case of the standalone product launch.